# Tilted Polarizer

Tags: visible-light, waves, polarization

[image: Polaroid_1]

[image: hyperphysics_malus_law]

[image: Polarizer]

I googled "polarizer film diagram" and "malu's law" and "polarizer physics" to obtain the pictures in this thread.
I understand we usually study polarised light phenomena by rotating polaroids.

I am curious about this : What would happen, or what would be the outcome/result if the first or second Polaroid in a setup shown in the above two images, is *tilted* forward or backwards? as in, the Polaroid is firm on it's base, just that it is *tilted* either forward or backwards. What would be the outcome when polarised light, and unpolarised light pass through the Polaroid?
Will light still pass through, or be polarised, through tilted Polaroid(s)?
Or is it just that Intensity will be affected, or Polarised light will not emerge straight, and rather at an angle?
Will light still be polarised the same way and angle as a untilted Polaroid(such as the base perpendicular to the table, untilted), just that less light is passed through?

Sorry I do not have a lab or the required gear to experiment this myself.

Secondary question :
How does the cross section of a Polariser looks like; how does a Polariser polarise light?
Isn't light polarised by passing through tiny vertical slits? Why is light not polarised through the tiny slits of a diffraction grating?
Is a Polariser made up of many sheets of polaroids?

Comment: Can you add the references of where you get those figures and texts, please?

Comment: for the images above, I googled "polarizer film diagram" and "malu's law" and "polarizer physics" to obtain the pictures in this thread, as stated above. As for the texts i've wrote, it is from me, i had some questions and i wrote it down above.

Comment: Tilting at an angle forwards or backwards won't have much effect accept that you may reflect slightly more light backwards, say from 3% to 5% or something.  Hitting the filter straight on provides the best efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

For an ideal polarizer, only the perpendicular angle matters.  Tilting it at an angle would have no effect.

For real polarizers, the base is going to cause some attenunation/reflection.  This is going to increase as the angle increases.  But I'm not aware of any specific corrections you'd apply.

> Isn't light polarised by passing through tiny vertical slits?

Light is polarized by selective removal of some of the light.  If you had an array of thin, closely spaced metal bars, then if a changing electric field is parallel to them, it will induce the charges in the bars to move.  This induced motion transfers power from the electric field into the material, absorbing it.  If the electric field is instead perpendicular to the bars, it cannot accelerate the charges and the field moves past with much less attenuation.

The polaroid material is similar, but instead of metal bars, it contains long chain molecules that allow charges to move easily along one axis, but not along the other.

Comment: Looking at this from the frame of reference of the polariser, light comes in from some Lx,Ly,Lz direction, and you're saying only the perpendicular angle matters, but I'm not sure how to apply this. Do I project the incoming light vendor onto the perpendicular(normal) for the polariser and then somehow adjust the polarisation of that light so that it's correct in this new reference frame? How to adjust it? Is there a way to do this solely by manipulating the Stokes parameters somehow? It's fairly clear how to rotate Stokes parameters to account for the polariser being rotated, but not tilted.